# requesting two Ajax

Tags: ajax, reference, instances

I'm trying to make two Ajax calls to get data to populate different bits of a web page, and as you'll already know, only the second happens.

So I thought I'd do this:

```
callAjax1('a'); callAjax2('b');

function callAjax1(data) {
 ajax(data);
}

function callAjax2(data) {
 ajax(data);
}

function ajax(data) {
 // calls XMLHttpRequestObject etc
}
```

The idea was that instead of calling ajax() twice, now, I'd have two independent instances of ajax that would run independently.

It works .. but only if I put in an alert at the top of ajax() to let me know I've arrived.

So I'm thinking that alert gives the first request time to finish before the second is called. Therefore, I've not managed to separate them properly into separate instances. Is that not possible?

What am I missing?

All the best
J

UPDATE:
I'm thinking this, do I stand a chance?

```
tParams = new Array (2); // we intend to call ajax twice
tParams[0] = new Array('ajaxGetDataController.php', 'PROJECT', 'id');
tParams[1] = new Array('ajaxGetFileController.php', 'FILE', 'projectId');

<select name='projectSelector' onchange=\"saveData(tParams, this.value);\">\n";

// gets called, twice
function saveData(pParams, pData) // pParams are: PageToRun, Table, Field
{
    if (XMLHttpRequestObject)
    {
        tPage = pParams[0][0]+'?table='+pParams[0][1]+'&pField='+pParams[0][2]+'&pData='+pData;
        XMLHttpRequestObject.open('GET', tPage);\n

        XMLHttpRequestObject.onreadystatechange = callAjax(pParams, pData);

        XMLHttpRequestObject.send(null);

    }   
}

function callAjax(pParams, pData)
{
 if (XMLHttpRequestObject.readyState == 4 &&    XMLHttpRequestObject.status == 200)
    {
        var tReceived = XMLHttpRequestObject.responseXML;
        options = tReceived.getElementsByTagName('option'); // fields and their values stored in simplest XML as options
        popForm(options, pParams[0][1]); // goes off to use the DOM to populate the onscreen form
        pParams.shift();    // cuts off pParams[0] and moves all elements up one
        if (pParams.length>0)
        {
            saveData(pParams, pData);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a ready state variable for the AJAX function:

```
function ajax(data) {
 readyState = false;
 // calls XMLHttpRequestObject etc
}
```

And then check for the ready state before executing the second call:

```
function callAjax2(data) {
if(readyState == true) {
 ajax(data);
 readyState = true;
 }
}
```

And make sure to change the readyState back to false after the AJAX calls have executed. This will ensure the first AJAX call has finished executing before the second one tries to fire.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at that today. Overnight, I thought I could make the call recursive, giving it an array of parameters where, at each call, it removes the top array element until the array is empty. Yours looks easier :-)

Comment: Isn't that just going to not execute the second call if it's not ready? It's not 'waiting' for it to be ready .. is it?

Comment: Do I stand a chance with this?

Comment: OK, I just updated my question above with the recursive thing I've got in mind .. does this feel like it'll work? I'll let y'all know.

Comment: I'm curious - is there a reason you're not using the jQuery AJAX library? the jQuery AJAX library has Callback support, which will allow you execute the second function when the first one completes.

Comment: Oh just pig-headedness. I'm new-ish to it, so I feel the need to really understand it before I hand everything over to a library. This is my first Ajax, so I wanted to eyeball it. Plus libraries .. you have to know the language, then you have to know the library. I'm a simple soul, in my heart, I feel better able when I'm coding raw. But I have put jQuery into this project for a popup calendar date chooser .. I didn't want to code that from scratch :-)

Comment: So how would I do it with jQuery (given that I have errors in mine)

Comment: Sample: $.get('myhtmlpage.html', myCallBack); From: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#Callback_and_Functions (This would be a get AJAX call to myhtmlpage.html that would then execute the function myCallBack when it completed.)

Comment: OK, I got my version working, I gave it 2 more hours. Not actually sure how I did it. There are obviously some basic JavaScript issues but as for the Ajax .. not sure what I changed tbh.

Comment: Oh, I did put callAjax back as an inner function, don't know why that would make a difference